# How to run a code on all symfony controllers?

Tags: symfony

i have RestAPI application i want to check token after call to my url.

my urls are like this: `127.0.0.1:8000/{api_token}/GetUsers`

and my api_token is generated like `md5('test'.time())`

my controller now is:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{api_token}")
 */
class UserController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @Rest\Get("/GetUsers")
     */
    public function getAction($api_token, Request $request)
    {
    if($api_token != $this->container->get('api_token')->getApiToken())
            return ['error'=> ['code' => 403, 'message' => 'Authentication failed']];

        //....
    }

    /**
     * @Rest\Post("/RegisterUser")
     */
    public function registerAction($api_token, Request $request)
    {
    if($api_token != $this->container->get('api_token')->getApiToken())
            return ['error'=> ['code' => 403, 'message' => 'Authentication failed']];

        //....
    }
}
```

this part of code is run in first of all my actions:

```
if($api_token != $this->container->get('api_token')->getApiToken())
                return ['error'=> ['code' => 403, 'message' => 'Authentication failed']];
```

what's the standard and better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a kernel.request event 
More info here

[Symfony events, Kernel-requets](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-request)

Each time Symfony receives a request triggers this event, so you can put your code on the event listener and it will be triggered on each request.